# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 search not working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am not a  Sharepoint Expert but I'll try to explain the problem and get help from you guys.

I'll keep it simple.

I have a Sharepoint Foundation with the following bindings in IIS:

```
 http://AAAAAAA:80
```

The SharePoint Foundation Search crawls using this URL:

```
  http://<computername>:80
```

I changed the bindings in IIS added the computer name and now it works.

I just don't want to have the computer name in the bindings. But I want the search to work.

Thanks.

Comment: You got to run a new crawling?

Comment: Thanks Tiago for the interest. What do you mean by "I got to run a new crawling" ?